# Customize Kendo Line Chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I want to customize kendo line chart as follows:

[image]

I want to show stacked bar chart at right side on kendo line chart.

Is there any way to achieve this using MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have null values for the bars except on the lase X value:

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OrOKi)**

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    title: {
        text: ""
    },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column",
        stack: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: "zone1",
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 45],
        color: "#f3ac32"
    }, {
        name: "zon2",
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 25],
        color: "#b8b8b8"
    }, {
        name: "zone3",
        data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 30],
        color: "#bb6e36"
    },
    {
        name: "The Line",
        data: [17, 17, 16, 28, 34, 30, 25, 30, 27, 37, 25, 33, 26, 36, 29],
        color: "#111111",
         type: "line"
    }],
    valueAxis: {
        max: 100,
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could have 2 charts side-by-side with the same min and max values on the value axis.